why crystal report design left space end line is small and on report run is too much?
I am working with Crystal Reports and facing an issue. I found that the left margin in the report design is small, but at runtime, the report appears larger than it does in design mode. I need to ensure that text extends to the last character on the line, but I am unable to do so. As a result, users see that the runtime report is very large, allowing only a single word to fit until the end of the line.
I have noticed that the left margin in the runtime display is significantly larger than in design mode. I am asking this question to understand the reason, as I need to write words up to the end of the line but am unable to achieve that.
Report example to be clearer:


The discrepancy between the margins in Crystal Reports at design time and runtime can occur for several reasons:

Printer Settings
Crystal Reports formats the report based on the default printer settings. At runtime, if the report is using a different printer driver or paper size than the one used during design, margins and layout may shift.
Solution: Ensure that the printer settings at runtime match those at design time. You can also set the report to use a specific printer or disable printer-dependent layout by setting the No Printer option in the report settings.
Page Setup Differences
The page size or orientation (e.g., A4 vs. Letter) specified at runtime may differ from the settings in the design environment.
Solution: Verify the page setup (size, orientation, and margins) in both environments and ensure consistency.
Scaling and Rendering Differences
The rendering engine at runtime may interpret certain layout elements (like margins, text, and graphical objects) differently than in the design tool, especially if the runtime environment uses a different version of Crystal Reports or a different framework for rendering (e.g., .NET or Java).
Solution: Test the report on the target runtime environment and adjust margins and layout in the design to accommodate these differences.
Subreport or Section Margins
If your report contains subreports, their margins can add to the overall margin size unexpectedly.
Solution: Check the margins of all subreports and sections and adjust them accordingly.
Viewer or Export Settings
If you’re viewing the report in a Crystal Reports viewer or exporting it (e.g., to PDF), the viewer or export engine might apply its own margin settings.
Solution: Review and adjust the viewer or export settings to ensure they align with your design.
Default System Printer Margin
At runtime, Crystal Reports uses the system’s default printer to calculate margins. Different printers have different minimum margin requirements, which can cause variations.
Solution: Set a consistent printer or ensure your design margins accommodate the printer with the largest minimum margin.

Debugging Tips:
Check Default Printer: Verify the default printer on both the development and runtime systems.
Preview in Runtime Environment: Test the report on the runtime machine using the same environment and settings.
Log Settings: Log the runtime environment’s printer and margin settings to identify discrepancies.
